# Problems in IntelliJ since version 2022.1 / java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: intellij-idea, noclassdeffounderror

As of today, when I try to run some of my programs in IntelliJ today, this message was shown:

```
Executing pre-compile tasks...
Loading Ant configuration...
Running Ant tasks...
Running 'before' tasks
Checking sources
Finished, saving caches…
Module 'Listen' production: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/DynamicBundle
Executing post-compile tasks...
Loading Ant configuration...
Running Ant tasks...
Synchronizing output directories...
13.04.22, 14:54 - Build completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 4 sec, 39 ms
```

This line is printed in red: *Module 'Listen' production: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/DynamicBundle*
I don't really have too much of an idea where I should look for the problem.
It seems to not have anything to do with the project itself. I already created a new Project and created a Hello World-program, which resulted in the same error.
Remarkably, yesterday my IntelliJ IDEA version was updated to version 2022.1.
Runtime version: 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.25 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
I have no idea either whether it has anything to do with the new version either.

I maintain another Project, which uses Scala language. That one is messed up even more:

```
Cannot process toolwindow sbt

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Missing implementation of resolved method 'abstract com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.settings.AbstractExternalSystemSettings getSettings(com.intellij.openapi.project.Project)' of abstract class com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.task.ui.AbstractExternalSystemToolWindowFactory.
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.task.ui.AbstractExternalSystemToolWindowFactory.shouldBeAvailable(AbstractExternalSystemToolWindowFactory.java:35)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializerKt.beanToTask(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt:262)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializerKt.beanToTask(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt:248)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializerKt.access$beanToTask(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt:1)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializerKt$computeToolWindowBeans$1.accept(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt:278)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializerKt$computeToolWindowBeans$1.accept(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.processWithPluginDescriptor(ExtensionPointImpl.java:301)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializerKt.computeToolWindowBeans(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt:274)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializer$1.get(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt:101)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializer$1.get(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt:83)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Any advice?

Best
Stapelüberläufer

Comment: This version was just released yesterday.  I think JetBrains support is your best bet.  I haven't even upgraded yet.

Comment: Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Intellij 2022.1

For me, the fix came from Gen's answer. I also had an old Scala plugin, and just removed it as I'm not using it anymore.

If you are looking to upgrade it, go to File -> Settings -> Plugins. From there just hit Upgrade for the plugins you want. After that restart the IDE.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Well, I just looked it up and saw that the Scala plugin is already updated to version 2022.1.13.

Comment: Thanks, this was it for me as well. Not even using Scala in the affected project but somehow the old plugin was causing a problem. Updating the plugin fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

I found that Scala plugin was not updated and updating it to at least version 2022.1.13 fixed it for me.

Comment: I would probably not mind upgrading. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded to `Intellij` 2022.1 and encountered this issue when trying to sync the old `gradles` projects that used to work for me :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/internal/impldep/com/google/common/collect/Lists
```

Cleaning the `caches` folder's content `(Gradle_HOME/caches)` resolved this issue for me

Make sure to also check that the `SDK` is correctly configured for your project (Java 17 by default) and the `Gradle` home is well specified in the `Settings>Gradle` section.

For info, I'm using `Java 8` and `Gradle 5.5.1` (yes I know :))

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply!
What is gradle? DO you think that would help my issue as well, since there is no reference to grade in the output line.
How can I configurre the project SDK properly? My Java SDK version is "java version 14.0.2", and as for the language level the menu entry says "SDK default (14 Switch expressions)".
I didn't yet ever pay attention to that.

Comment: Hello, Gradle is a build automation tool for multi-language software development. You can see it as Maven if you're more familiar with the latter. I don't know if it could resolve your issue but that might be the case. To configure properly your SDK, you can go to Settings>SDK, and here you can refer to a local downloaded JDK or let IntelliJ download one for you. Gradle uses the JDK that's why it was important for me to point out the concordance of the versions. Please let us know, if it helped.

Comment: Thank you, well I just saw how to update my Scala plugin to 2022.1.13 and that fixed the issue in my Scala project.

My

Comment: My Java project, however is still faulty.
Trying to run a class, this is shown:

Comment: Executing pre-compile tasks...
Loading Ant configuration...
Running Ant tasks...
Running 'before' tasks
Checking sources
Searching for compilable files... [Listen]
Parsing java… [Listen]
java: JPS incremental annotation processing is disabled. Compilation results on partial recompilation may be inaccurate. Use build process "jps.track.ap.dependencies" VM flag to enable/disable incremental annotation processing environment.
java: Multiple encodings set for module chunk Listen
"UTF-16" will be used by compiler
(...)

Comment: And if I set to Language level 17, it says:
java: error: release version 17 not supported

Comment: Maybe you probably need to downgrade your Java Version. Try to use v11 or v1.8

Comment: Thank you. Problem is solved now. I'm using language level 17 now and I added the right SDK! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrade the Scala Plugin and its done!

Answer (score 0):

visiting
[scala plugin's page](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1347-scala)

and install it from there worked for me on ultimate version 2022.2.3

Answer (score 0):

After recent intellij update to version 2023.1
I was getting below error while running any unit tests which were running fine before update:

```
intellij build error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/ints/Int2ObjectMap
```

Restarting intellij helped resolve the issue for me.